# Questionmark in url

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use this http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source with Laravel and so I need to send a GET request to a url which ends with "?term=foo". I've tried to escape the "?" with a backslash, which doesn't work. To clarify, this is what I want:

```
Route::get('search\?term=(:any)', function()
{
      //do something
}
```

Is it possible to have questionmarks in the url with Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a question mark in the URL should make no difference. You're using a PHP framework, and simply speaking, `...?term=parameters` should not be problematic. To my knowledge, there should be no need to escape such a question mark... It is handled appropriately by default.

Comment: Yes, this was just me being stupid. $term = Input::get('term'); is what was needed, instead of trying to extract the parameter with the routing.

Comment: Well, what if we have defined a custom route which ends with the parameter (ex: `dictionary/{word}`) in this case question mark would be translated as the end of url and start of parameters not a part of parameter

Answer (score 4):

Just for others who may want a **Clear Answer** :

you have to write and use your code as follows:

```
Route::get('search', function()
{
      $term = Input::get('term');
      if(isset($term)){
         //do other stuff ! 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the slug function is what you are looking for: http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Str.html

From the API Doc:

```
slug( string $title, string $separator = '-' )
```

Generate a URL friendly "slug" from a given string.